# url request working in Postman but not in php curl or command line

Tags: php, shell, curl, postman

This is the request I'm trying. But the url works and returns HTML in browser & POSTMAN but not in php curl or command line.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.walmart.com/header?mobileResponsive=true",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
       "cache-control: no-cache",
       "postman-token: 04275e89-412a-edbf-a63d-d6ebe5c3c126"
    ),
 ));

 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $err = curl_error($curl);

 curl_close($curl);

 if ($err) {
   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
 } else {
   echo $response;
 }
```

Try same URL from command line

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'http://www.walmart.com/header?mobileResponsive=true' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'postman-token: 301d71b1-fde5-a66f-2433-ed6baf9c8426'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you try in verbose mode with [`-v`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v), you will see that the request is redirected from http to https :

```
curl -v http://www.walmart.com/header?mobileResponsive=true

*   Trying 23.200.157.25...
* Connected to www.walmart.com (23.200.157.25) port 80 (#0)
> GET /header?mobileResponsive=true HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.walmart.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 54
```

Use the https location :

```
curl "https://www.walmart.com/header?mobileResponsive=true"
```

Or if you want curl to perform a new request at the new location use [`-L`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) (`--location`) :

```
curl -L "http://www.walmart.com/header?mobileResponsive=true"
```

Note :

- you don't need [`-X/--request`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X), the default method is `GET`
- you don't need your postman headers for getting the response

In your PHP code, the same apply :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.walmart.com/header?mobileResponsive=true",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}

?>
```